# Qiskit Nature VQE print full quantum circuit

Tags: qiskit

I am doing VQE using Qiskit Nature. I want to see how my final quantum circuit looks like. How to print the whole quantum circuit (like an ansatz)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `construct_circuit` method for that. E.g. (assuming you have the latest Qiskit release installed)

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2
from qiskit.opflow import X, Y, Z

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
hamiltonian = X ^ Y ^ Z
ansatz = EfficientSU2(3)
optimizer = SPSA()
parameters = list(ansatz.parameters)

vqe = VQE(ansatz, optimizer, quantum_instance=backend)
circuits = vqe.construct_circuit(parameters, hamiltonian)

for circuit in circuits:
    print(circuit.draw())
```

which prints

```
      ┌──────────┐┌───────────┐          ┌───────────┐┌───────────┐                       ┌───────────┐┌───────────┐                       ┌───────────┐┌───────────┐
q_0: ─┤ RY(θ[0]) ├┤ RZ(θ[17]) ├──■────■──┤ RY(θ[20]) ├┤ RZ(θ[23]) ├───────────────■────■──┤ RY(θ[17]) ├┤ RZ(θ[20]) ├───────────────■────■──┤ RY(θ[23]) ├┤ RZ(θ[13]) ├─────────────────────────
     ┌┴──────────┤├───────────┤┌─┴─┐  │  └───────────┘├───────────┤┌───────────┐┌─┴─┐  │  └───────────┘├───────────┤┌───────────┐┌─┴─┐  │  └───────────┘├───────────┤┌───────────┐┌─────┐┌───┐
q_1: ┤ RY(θ[11]) ├┤ RZ(θ[18]) ├┤ X ├──┼────────■──────┤ RY(θ[21]) ├┤ RZ(θ[11]) ├┤ X ├──┼────────■──────┤ RY(θ[18]) ├┤ RZ(θ[21]) ├┤ X ├──┼────────■──────┤ RY(θ[10]) ├┤ RZ(θ[14]) ├┤ SDG ├┤ H ├
     ├───────────┤├───────────┤└───┘┌─┴─┐    ┌─┴─┐    ├───────────┤├───────────┤└───┘┌─┴─┐    ┌─┴─┐    ├───────────┤├───────────┤└───┘┌─┴─┐    ┌─┴─┐    ├───────────┤├───────────┤└┬───┬┘└───┘
q_2: ┤ RY(θ[16]) ├┤ RZ(θ[19]) ├─────┤ X ├────┤ X ├────┤ RY(θ[22]) ├┤ RZ(θ[16]) ├─────┤ X ├────┤ X ├────┤ RY(θ[19]) ├┤ RZ(θ[22]) ├─────┤ X ├────┤ X ├────┤ RY(θ[12]) ├┤ RZ(θ[15]) ├─┤ H ├──────
     └───────────┘└───────────┘     └───┘    └───┘    └───────────┘└───────────┘     └───┘    └───┘    └───────────┘└───────────┘     └───┘    └───┘    └───────────┘└───────────┘ └───┘
```

which is the ansatz plus Basis transformation gates (H and Sdg at the very end) to map from the Pauli-X and -Y basis to the computational basis.